# Parsing class hierarchy using JaxB

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have class hierarchy

```
interface Intf {}

Class A implements Intf{}

Class B implements Intf{}
```

Now I am using above `Class A` and `Class B` to read two diffrent XML files with the elp of JaxB. Can any one suggest me how to configure and use structure like above in JaxB?

Comment: Could you provide some additional information?  As the question stands the interface doesn't factor in as it will be ignored.

Comment: Also, which JAXB provider are you going to use? F.e. **Jackson** supports [JAXB annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) with good polymorphic type handling and it is typical JAXB provider for big number of technologies: CXF, RestEasy etc.

Comment: @n1ckolas - Jackson is not a JAXB (JSR-222) provider.  While several JAX-RS implementations utilize Jackson as an approach for their JSON-binding I am not aware of any that use it for XML-binding.

Comment: Please check this project: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider

Comment: @n1ckolas - The `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` impl offered by Jackson is compatible with any JAX-RS compliant implementation.  But it is not the default (couldn't be as Jackson does not pass the JAXB TCK, it couldn't as the Jackson docs state there are unsupported annotations), and does not mean it is even included by JAX-RS impls.

Comment: I'm not telling it is *default*, I'm telling that it is *typical*, i.e. very widespread, because it's very fast and customizable. Particular, it has very good support of polymorphic types. F.e. personally me used Jackson both for JSON and XML REST-API with the same set of annotations and with reusing the same JAX-RS services (Apache CXF).

Comment: @n1ckolas- Basicaly I just want to create class hierarchy from two diffrent xml files. You can say Abstract class instead Interface.

Comment: Could you add some additional information about your use case?  I've written several articles about JAXB and inheritance, maybe one of them is what you are looking for: http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case the interface doesn't factor in.  If you want to map `A` and `B` to different XML structures you can go ahead and do so, I'll demonstrate below with an example.

**JAVA MODEL**

***IntF***

```
public interface IntF {

    public String getFoo();

    public void setFoo(String foo);

}
```

***A***

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class A implements IntF {

    private String foo;

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name="renamed-foo")
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

***B***

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class B implements IntF {

    private String foo;

    @Override
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

**DEMO CODE**

***Demo***

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class, B.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        A a = new A();
        a.setFoo("Hello World");
        marshaller.marshal(a, System.out);

        B b = new B();
        b.setFoo("Hello World");
        marshaller.marshal(b, System.out);
    }

}
```

***Output***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
    <renamed-foo>Hello World</renamed-foo>
</a>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b foo="Hello World"/>
```

Comment: Hi Blaise, in `CLass A` I have other class say SubA and in this class have attributes. Same in case of `Class B` too. This configuration I can't do as u suggested. Else how can I do?

Comment: @Navnath - Can you edit your question to include a simplified version of your model?

Comment: I have extend this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741264/jaxb-to-read-class-hierarchy)