# JaxB to read class hierarchy

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

Just extending [Parsing class hierarchy using JaxB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676401/parsing-class-hierarchy-using-jaxb) question.
Want to read following xml file using JaxB

```
<IMPORT>
    <TABLE NAME="USER">
        <ROW>
            <USER_ID>1</USER_ID>
            <ROW_VERSION>1</ROW_VERSION>
            <USER_NAME>Navnath</USER_NAME>
            <LOGIN>Navnath</LOGIN>
            <LOGIN_PASSWORD>Navnath</LOGIN_PASSWORD>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <USER_ID>2</USER_ID>
            <ROW_VERSION>1</ROW_VERSION>
            <USER_NAME>Kumbhar</USER_NAME>
            <LOGIN>Kumbhar</LOGIN>
            <LOGIN_PASSWORD>Kumbhar</LOGIN_PASSWORD>
        </ROW>
    </TABLE>

    <TABLE NAME="WORK">
        <ROW>
            <WORK_ID>1</WORK_ID>
            <WORK_NAME>Work1</WORK_NAME>
            <ROW_VERSION TYPE="N">1</ROW_VERSION>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <WORK_ID>2</WORK_ID>
            <WORK_NAME>Work2</WORK_NAME>
            <ROW_VERSION TYPE="N">1</ROW_VERSION>
        </ROW>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE> ... </TABLE>
    <TABLE> ... </TABLE>
    <TABLE> ... </TABLE>
</IMPORT>
```

You can see in above xml file is column names are different in each table. I want to insert this data in database. I try to create class hierarchy for this, But I don't know how to do this. My ROW class will contains diffrent xml element per table and this is the area which I am not able to configure. Please suggest.

Comment: You're looking to key the particular implementing class based on the 'NAME' attribute so as to determine the class to use to load the ROW data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could leverage MOXy's `@XmlDescriminatorNode`/`@XmlDescriminatorValue` extension for this use case (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html).

**Import**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="IMPORT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Import {

    @XmlElement(name="TABLE")
    private List<Table> tables;

}
```

**Table**

The `@XmlDescriminatorNode` annotation is used to specify the XML attribute that will be used to indicate which subclass will be instantiated.  A JAXB implementation can't pull in the subclasses of a class via reflection, we will use the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation to reference them.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorNode;

@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@NAME")
@XmlSeeAlso({UserTable.class, WorkTable.class})
public abstract class Table {

}
```

**UserTable**

The `@XmlDescriminatorValue` annotation is used to specify the value of the `NAME` attribute that corresponds to a particular subclass.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorValue;

@XmlDiscriminatorValue("USER")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserTable extends Table {

    @XmlElement(name="ROW")
    private List<UserRow> rows;

}
```

**UserRow**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class UserRow {

    @XmlElement(name="USER_ID")
    private int userID;

    @XmlElement(name="USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

}
```

**WorkTable**

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorValue;

@XmlDiscriminatorValue("WORK")
public class WorkTable extends Table {

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Import.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum15741264/input.xml");
        Import result = (Import) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(result, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

Below is the input to and output from running the demo code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IMPORT>
   <TABLE NAME="USER">
      <ROW>
         <USER_ID>1</USER_ID>
         <USER_NAME>Navnath</USER_NAME>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
         <USER_ID>2</USER_ID>
         <USER_NAME>Kumbhar</USER_NAME>
      </ROW>
   </TABLE>
   <TABLE NAME="WORK"/>
</IMPORT>
```

**Alternative Solutions**

Alternatively using only the standard JAXB APIs you could try the following approach using an `XmlAdapter`

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

Comment: I try this code but got exception `Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeDirectCollectionMapping[ROW]] 
with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(org.jaxb.UserTable --> [])], could not be converted to [class org.jaxb.UserRow].
 at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(ConversionException.java:71)`

Comment: @Navnath - Can you try the code with EclipseLink 2.4.1:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/.  Also if you send me a note through my contact package I will email you the code:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html